# Unable to find this specific issue answered: Creating subclasses, 2nd subclass causing: Exception has occurred: TypeError Admin() takes no arguments

Tags: python, subclassing

The Admin subclass works fine until I add the second User subclass. Then I get the error. I am entering this exactly as it is printed in the book. Do I have to add a second **init**, is there a misprint in the book?

```
import datetime as dt

class Member:

    free_days = 365

class Admin(Member):

    pass

class User(Member):
    
    pass

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.free_days = dt.date.today() + dt.timedelta(days=self.free_days)

Ann = Admin("Annie", "Angst")
print(Ann.firstname)
print(Ann.lastname)
print(Ann.free_days)
print()

Uli = User("Uli", "Ungula")
print(Uli.firstname)
print(Uli.lastname)
print(Uli.free_days)
```

This is the result from running the code BEFORE the class

```
User(Member): info is added:

Annie

Angst

2022-06-13
```

When I enter everything for class `User(Member)`: and the `User` info, I get this:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
Admin() takes no arguments
  File "C:\Users\miki_\Desktop\AIO Python\CreatingAClassAndSubclass", line 19, in <module>
    Ann = Admin("Annie", "Angst")
```

Comment: Try using super.__init__

Comment: The `Admin` class has no `__init__()` method. You can't pass parameters when creating an `Admin`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. `Admin("Annie", "Angst")` throws and exception regardless of whether the `User` class is there.

Comment: If you are looking at the book `Python All-in-One For Dummies` it seems like they put the `__init__` function on the `Member` class, which makes sense.

Comment: I tried using super__init__ with no luck. I am new to Python. I don't understand what it means that you can pass parameters when creating an Admin. If this is something you can do, I don't understand why the book says to do it. The code runs fine until class User(Member): is added. Yes, the Python All-in-One for Dummies is what I am working from.